# Python >> operator

Tags: javascript, python

I have the following code

```
a = 449834688
d = 10
```

if I do

```
d = a << d
```

I get back `460630720512`

When I use the same numbers in javascript `a << d` I get back

`1069219840`

Why the number difference? Is also `>>` same as `>>>` ?

Comment: Javascript bitwise operations behave "as if" on 32bit integers. I don't know python well, but your result there is above 32 bit. For the other things, i don't understand what's so hard to google here - [MDN Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: `a << d & 0xFFFFFFFF` You should "cut" 32 bit manually

Comment: Python is not restricted to 32bits so you can use ie. `d=100000` and `a<<d` gives you very,very long number - more then 30 000 digits - `len(str(a << d))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght this solved it! Additionally How can I use modulus to return my result in 32 bit and also handle negative or positive number?

Comment: @Dilli, you can apply [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) here. Something like this: `ctypes.c_uint32(a << d)`.